# How can i have multiple data arrays for uipickerviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

What I am trying to accomplish: I have 5 different UITextfields. I want the user to be able to fill in these fields using UIPickerviews. Also i want each of the pickerviews to have a different ranges and/or types of values to choose from for each text field.

I've tried doing this using multiple pickerviews with different arrays for each textfield using switch statements. However I don't feel that this is the most efficient way to go about implementing this. Could someone shed some light on the best practises in implementing different data arrays for pickerviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you are doing with help of just one PickerView with the following code

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerSelected) {

        case LANGUAGE:
            return [languageArray count];
            break;
        case GENDER:
            return [genderArray count];
            break;
        case COUNTRY:
            return [countryArray count];
            break;
        case CITY:
            return [cityArray count];
            break;

        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerSelected) {

        case LANGUAGE:
            return [languageArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case GENDER:
            return [genderArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;

        case COUNTRY:
            return [[countryArray objectAtIndex:row] countryName];
            break;

        case CITY:
            return [cityArray objectAtIndex:row];

        default:
            return @"";
            break;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

- Where `languageArray` , `genderArray`, `countryArray` represent your
  different arrays
- and `pickerSelected` can be an `enum` or an `int` value which you can set according to different UITextField's.
  Each UITextField will have unique value for PickerView

Answer (score 2):

Take one array mutable or immutable as per need and textField Declare in .m file.

Use TextField Delegate method :

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
      currentText=textField;
    if (textField==yourTextfield)
    {
        arrCurrent=YourCurrentArray;
        [yourTextfield setInputView:pickerObj];
        [pickerObj setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [yourTextfield setInputAccessoryView:toolObj];
        [self pickerView:pickerObj didSelectRow:[pickerObj selectedRowInComponent:0] inComponent:0];

    }
    else if (textField==yourTextfield2)
    {
        arrCurrent=YourCurrentArray2;
        [yourTextfield2 setInputView:pickerObj];
        [pickerObj setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [yourTextfield2 setInputAccessoryView:toolObj];
        [self pickerView:pickerObj didSelectRow:[pickerObj selectedRowInComponent:0] inComponent:0];

    }
    }
```

In pickerView Delegate :

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

        [currentText setText:[arrCurrent objectAtIndex:row]];

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:
(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [arrCurrent objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

Hope will be helpful to you.. :)

Comment: What if the type of objects are different in each array & title cannot be retrieved from a single property ?

Comment: @PiyushSharma it is only work on textField because only textfield Provide to add inputview .... and jobs Wrote that he is using 5 textfield thats y I suggest him. and i just gave tftitle gor example.

Comment: He also wrote   'Also i want each of the pickerviews to have a different ranges and/or types of values to choose from for each text field'. that means type of array will be different for each textField

Comment: of course it will change. you need to store in current array. @PiyushSharma

Comment: @PiyushSharma i update my answer  , hope you misunderstanding is solved.

Comment: what you need to change is the - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:
(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component          where you need to convert objectAtIndex:row   to fetch the property which you need to show in the pickerView.  For each array this fetching can vary so there also manipulation of object needs to be done.

Comment: yeah , it can be done by self. common i will not wrote whole stuff here. he can retrieve array , which he want to fetch in pickerview . And for your confusion when you write some stuff in current array.  you need to retrive by using like  [yourArray valueFoeKey:@"key"];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93673/discussion-between-piyushsharma-and-meera).